# Things are accessible and being logged, but not coming in response of NestJs API

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, nestjs-typeorm

I am facing a strange issue in my nestjs application, I implemented pagination using postgres and typeorm for getting list of stores. I was able to get the list of stores. Later I added totalPages in my response to let the frontend know how upto how many pages it can send in the query, but as soon as I added (refer the code below for more details) `{stores, totalPages}` the response is coming to as an empty array and I am unable to understand why because when I try to do `console.log({stores, totalPages})`, everything is being logged and the very next line when I try to return these things, they are not coming in the reponse.

````
    if (!perPage || perPage < 1) {
      perPage = 100;
    }

    const count = await this.repo.count();
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(count / perPage);

    // pageNumber = 1 by default
    if (!pageNumber || pageNumber < 1) {
      pageNumber = 1;
    }
    // if page number exceeds total possible pages
    if (pageNumber > totalPages) {
      pageNumber = totalPages;
    }

    // calculate number of rows to skip
    const skip = (pageNumber - 1) * perPage;
    const stores = await this.repo.find({
      order: { createdAt: 'ASC' },
      take: perPage,
      skip
    });
    console.log({ totalPages, stores }); // { totalPages: 1, stores: [...All My Stores] } 
    // are being logged, things are accessible until this point
    return { totalPages, stores }; // returns {} in postman```
````

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel, sure... sorry for the formatting, comment is not letting me format the code properly, but I hope you will get the idea

```@Get()
  findAll(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Query('perPage') perPage: number,
    @Query('pageNumber') pageNumber: number,
  ): Promise<{stores: Store[], totalPages: number}> {
    return this.StoresServiceFactory.getService().findWithRelation(
      req.currentUserClaimSet.id,
      perPage,
      pageNumber,
    );
  }```

Comment: You know you can edit your question with more information, right? No need to put a badly formatted code block in the comments

Comment: you know that when I can't answer a question, I can put a question on a question, right?

Answer (score 0):

If console.log is logging what you require, the problem most likely is in the controller. You probably forgot to return and await the service in the controller.
If that is not the case you can console.log the service method you are calling in the controller.
Also, I would advise you to not use skip in as it may have performance issues when working in a larger database. It is because skip requires the database to scan and skip rows before returning the desired result. You can instead ask the client to send the id of the last row of the previous page and use the greater than operator to retrieve the data.

```
const stores = await this.repo.find({
  where: {
    id: MoreThan(lastPageId)
  },
  order: {
    createdAt: 'ASC'
  },
  take: perPage
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Adarsh Singh, use JSON.stringfy at return, like this:

```
return JSON.stringfy({ totalPages, stores });
```